# Why won't Mathematica simplify this expression?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

The code

```
myp = b^2 + (m^2 + 1)*x^2 + 2*x*(mb - (r + s)) + r^2 + 2*r*s
d = Discriminant[myp, x]
Solve[d == 0, s] // Factor // FullySimplify
```

returns

```
FullySimplify[{{s -> 
    mb + m^2 r - Sqrt[(1 + m^2) (b^2 + 2 mb r + m^2 r^2)]}, {s -> 
    mb + m^2 r + Sqrt[(1 + m^2) (b^2 + 2 mb r + m^2 r^2)]}}]
```

but does not pull out the square under the radical:

```
Factor[b^2 + 2 m b r + m^2 r^2] 
(b+m r)^2
```

Why does Mathematica not simplify further? And how do I tell it to do so?

By hand, I get $s = (mr+b)(m \pm \sqrt{m^2 + 1})$.  I'd like to:

1. Minimum: Check my work with Mathematica
2. Manually get Mathematica to check my work
3. Ideally: Get Mathematica to simplify it "by itself" (that is, without me having to first figure the simple version by hand)

---

## Update

In order to avoid the [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), I'll explain what I'm trying to solve:

> Given a circle $C$, a point on the circle $P$, and a line $\ell$, find the circle $Q$ that is tangent to $C$ at $P$ and tangent to $\ell$, using analytic geometry.

[image]

*Note: The picture uses different names than what I've used here.  The picture was constructed using synthetic geometry; my goal now is to use analytic geometry to find $s$*.

Solution: Let $C$ be centered on the origin and have radius $r$, and let $\ell$ have equation $y = mx + b$.  Assume WLOG that $P$ is on the x-axis.

The center of the circle to be constructed must be on the x-axis as well.  Let $s$ be the *unknown* radius of the circle to be constructed.  Then we are given $r, m, b$ and want to find values of $s$ such that the system of equations $$y = mx+b\\(x-(r+s))^2 + y^2 = s^2$$ has **exactly one** solution.

We substitute the first equation into the second, and find values for $s$ where the discriminant is $0$.  Doing this by hand, I get $$s = (mr+b)(m \pm \sqrt{m^2 + 1}).$$

How can I **solve this directly in Mathematica** without having to do it by hand first?

Comment: *Mathematica* is working fine.  `FullySimplify` should be `FullSimplify`.

Comment: @JimB `FullSimplfiy` still doesn't pull out the squared factor: `FullSimplify[Solve[d == 0, s]]` gives `{{s -> mb + m^2 r - Sqrt[(1 + m^2) (b^2 + 2 mb r + m^2 r^2)]}, {s -> 
   mb + m^2 r + Sqrt[(1 + m^2) (b^2 + 2 mb r + m^2 r^2)]}} `

Comment: You're learning a new language and you shouldn't assume so much.  Read the documentation on `FullSimplify` and know that *Mathematica* (generally) assumes all variables are complex so using the `Assumptions` option in `FullSimplify` gives the necessary simplification to result in the appearance you think the result should have.  Also, there are many ways to get the same result as shown by @Syed 's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

The fact that `FullySimplify` appeared in your output indicates that Mathematica did not have a definition for that function and was unable to evaluate its output. Highlighting it and pressing `F1` for help, takes you to search results with the correctly spelled [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) at the top.

As  Syed pointed out, [`PowerExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand.html) will simplify; however, caution is required. `PowerExpand` makes assumptions ("The transformations made by PowerExpand are correct in general only if c is an integer or a and b are positive real numbers.") which requires you to ensure that these assumptions are valid. Consequently, it is generally best to explicitly use all appropriate assumptions with either `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` rather than using `PowerExpand`. Further, these assumptions should also be used with [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) to facilitate arriving at the intended result.

```
myp = b^2 + (m^2 + 1)*x^2 + 2*x*(m  b - (r + s)) + r^2 + 2*r*s;
d = Discriminant[myp, x];
```

From your explanation, the appropriate constraints/assumptions are `r > 0` and `s > 0` and if `PowerExpand` were used would imply `b + m*r > 0`

```
Assuming[{r > 0, s > 0, b + m*r > 0},
 Solve[d == 0, s] // Simplify]

(* {{s -> (m + Sqrt[1 + m^2]) (b + m r)}} *)
```

The [`Assuming`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html) construct makes the given assumptions available to all encompassed functions that use the option [`Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html).

Consequently, the results equivalent to using `PowerExpand` are obtained by explicitly using the assumptions that would be implied by using `PowerExpand`.

However, more generally,

```
Assuming[{r > 0, s > 0, {b, m} ∈ Reals},
 Solve[d == 0, s] // Simplify]

(* {{s -> m (b + m r) + Sqrt[1 + m^2] Abs[b + m r]}} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

With minor corrections:

```
myp = b^2 + (m^2 + 1)*x^2 + 2*x*(m b - (r + s)) + r^2 + 2*r*s;
d = Discriminant[myp, x];
Solve[d == 0, s] // Factor // PowerExpand // FullSimplify
```

$\left\{\left\{s\to \left(m-\sqrt{m^2+1}\right) (b+m r)\right\},\left\{s\to \left(\sqrt{m^2+1}+m\right) (b+m r)\right\}\right\}$

Comment: Thanks! 1. Besides adding `PowerExpand`, what other corrections were needed? 2. If I hadn't already solved the problem by hand, how would I know I need `PowerExpand` (or even `Factor`)? And if I have to first solve it by hand to use MMA, how do I use MMA effectively (other than to check my work)?

Comment: A space between `mb` is required to make it a product of two variables. `FullySimplify` should be `FullSimplify`. Expressions can be simplified into many forms; so going from one form to another is not an exact science. `PowerExpand` would do simplifications when radicals and powers are present.